# Python Selenium find_element_by_link_text not working for me

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to have Selenium log me into Soundcloud but the find_element_by_link_text attribute isn't working for me but it seems to work for "Find out more" and "Upload your own". Why is it working for some of the elements on the web page but not others??

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/quanahbennett/PycharmProjects/SeleniumTest/chromedriver')
url= "https://soundcloud.com/"
driver.get(url)
#time.sleep(30)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in');
link.click()


breakpoint()
```

Comment: There are several reasons. The element may be in an iframe, the element may not actually be in the page, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drakepolo,

```
find_element_by_link_text()
```

function only work for text which are enclosed in anchor tag (sometimes they are called a tag).

Below is the `outerHTML` for `Upload your own`

```
<a href="/upload" class="frontContent__uploadButton sc-button sc-button-cta sc-button-primary sc-button-large">Upload your own</a>
```

See here the text `Upload your own` is in enclosed in a tag in HTML.

But for `Sign In`  button :

```
<button type="button" class="g-opacity-transition frontHero__loginButton g-button-transparent-inverted sc-button sc-button-medium loginButton" tabindex="0" title="Sign in" aria-label="Sign in">Sign in</button>
```

it is wrapped inside in a button tag.

So that is the reason  `find_element_by_link_text()` will not work for `Sign In` button.

You can switch to `css selector` like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.frontHero__loginButton')
```

or `xpath using` :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'frontHero__loginButton')]")
```

Note that **CSS** has more precedence than **xpath**.

Comment: Thank you!!! may I ask how you knew the XPath of the element though. I cant seem to understand that

Comment: `//tagName[@attributeName='attributeValue']` this is a basic syntax for XPath. Selenium uses XPath v1.0. There are newer versions like v2.0 and v3.0. `contains` is basically a xpath method that I have used. Please read more about it here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: The convention in SO is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Element you are trying to find `Sign in` is not in a `a` tag to use `driver.find_element_by_link_text`. Its in a `button` tag.

Try like below and confirm:

```
driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Cookie pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

# Click on Sign-in
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='frontHero__signin']//button[@title='Sign in']"))).click()
```

Comment: I used these lines of code and received the error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point

Comment: Actually I apologize, once I removed the line of code for the cookie pop-up it worked perfectly, thank you!! may I ask though how did you retrieve the XPath for the element? I dont know how to do that

Comment: @drakepolo - You can refer these links as of now - [LInk1](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/find-element-by-xpath-in-selenium), [Link2](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)